# img tag in html which one is right?

Tags: html, image, tags, src

```
<img src='stackoverflow.png'>
<img src='stackoverflow.png'></img> -- is it right? or can I use it?
<img src='stackoverflow.png' />
```

in these three code
is the second code is right?
or can I use it to show images on a website?
and it will show if it will show why I can't use it?

Answer (score 0):

all of the above is right
Syntax of img tag in HTML is

```
 **<img src="URL/PATH">**
```

as per above syntax `<img src='stackoverflow.png'>` is right so it will work.
 tag is not necessary but you can put it so it will also work.
and third one means you are closing the image tag and as i said to close image tag is not necessary

Answer (score -1):

No, the second one is wrong, the first and third are fine. I personally recomend the third because it makes your code more redable. You can find out more at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: What does _"the third is the best, and the first is fine"_ even mean?